# Parquet File datetime value mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parquet

While reading a parquet file using pandas the values in the datetime field gets changing. For example the output of the field while reading a parquet file is 2021-02-07 10:43:20.067 but the actual value should be there is 2021-02-07 6:43:20. Same way for few records the datetime columns are seeing +4 and +5 hrs. All the date min and sec is same but only hours field is getting changed.

The below code I am using

```
df=pd.read_parquet('filename.parquet')
```

The data type for all the fields in parquet are `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: I assume you'll want to convert the input date/time to a certain time zone. So what tz is the input in, what should the output be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I suspect that it may have to do with timezones that have daylight saving. if you think this is the reason, then I would do:
​

```
​pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])\
    ​.dt.tz_localize('UTC')\
    .dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')
```

The first line makes sure the column is in date-time format so the subsequent lines will work.

The second line defines the timezone as used in producing the parquet file.

The third line converts the timezone to the one that you are interested in.