# Reading parquet file in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parquet

I am trying to read a parquet files to pandas

```
data=pd.read_parquet('MyFiles.parquet', engine='pyarrow')
```

but I am getting the following error

```
ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[us] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp: 253402214400000000
```

If I change the engine type to fastparquet

```
 data=pd.read_parquet('MyFiles.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
```

There is also this error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tz'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the column which has timestamp in different timezone. You might need to download the parquet file first, and modify it before convert to pandas DataFrame.
Some related issues: [Parquet File datetime value mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71025315/parquet-file-datetime-value-mismatch)